# Beaglebone Black; Wrong SPI Frequency

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, spi

I'm new at programming the Beaglebone Black and to Linux in general, so I'm trying to figure out what's happening when I'm setting up a SPI-connection. I'm running Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47.

I have set up a SPI-connection, using a Device Tree Overlay, and I'm now running [spidev_test.c](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev_test.c) to test the connection. For the application I'm making, I need a quite specific frequency. So when I run spidev_test and measure the frequency of the bits shiftet out, I don't get the expected frequency.

[image]

I'm sending a SPI-packet containing 0xAA, and in spidev_test I've modified the "**spi_ioc_transfer.speed_hz**" to 4000000 (4MHz). But I'm measuring a data transfer frequency of 2,98MHz. I'm seeing the same result with other speeds as well, deviations are usually around 25-33%.

**How come the measured speed doesn't match the assigned speed?**
      *How is the speed assigned in "speed_hz" defined?*
      *How precise should I expect the frequency to be?*

Thank you :)

Comment: What speed is it reporting is having successfully set? The `max speed:` printout from the `spidev_test.c` program should tell you something, at least. Also check for kernel errors with `dmesg`.

Comment: The `max speed:` printout just gives me the speed I've defined. In the example above it would print 4000000.
Nothing appears in `dmesg`

Comment: Did you find out why? How many bytes are you transferring at once? I noticed data corruption at certain clock rates.. Try higher clock rate such as 16Mhz and do a bigger transaction so DMA can kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Actually If you look closely on the DSO you can see that each clock cycles takes approx 312.5 ns , which makes the clock frequency to be **3.2Mhz,**. May be the channel you're monitoring i

Then, the variation between the expected & actual speed,
In microncontrollers I've worked the all the peripherlas including the SPI derives ots clock from the Master clock which is supplied to the MCU(in your case MPU), the master frequency divided by some prescalar gives the frequency for periperal opearations, where as peripherals use this frequency and uses its prescalar for controlling the baud rate,

So in your case suppose if the master frequency is not proper this could lead to the behavior mentioned above.

So you have two options
1. Correct the MPU core frequency
2. Do a trial & error method to find the value which has to be given is spi test program to get the desired frequency

Comment: What is the DSO?
I have tried setting the speed to 3,2 MHz, but then the measurement gave me 2,98 MHz. I measured the same 2,98 MHz, when I set the speed at 3 MHz, so it seems that 2,98 MHz is one of frequencies that the prescaler can output.